# Jmeter ::: java.io.IOException: Unable to delete file: D:\temp\result.csv

Tags: jmeter

I've wrote following code in  tear down step of "bean shell post proccessor" to delete all  CSV files that are created in "one thread group" and accessed in "different thread group" in same Test plan.

Code:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
try {
FileUtils.cleanDirectory(new File("D:/temp"));
} catch (Exception ex) {
log.info("Script execution failed", ex);
}
```

Am getting following Exception

```
jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement: Script execution failed java.io.IOException: Unable to delete file: D:\temp\result.csv
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceDelete(FileUtils.java:2279)
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.cleanDirectory(FileUtils.java:1653)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at bsh.Reflect.invokeMethod(Reflect.java:134)
at bsh.Reflect.invokeStaticMethod(Reflect.java:98)
at bsh.Name.invokeMethod(Name.java:874)
at bsh.BSHMethodInvocation.eval(BSHMethodInvocation.java:75)
at bsh.BSHPrimaryExpression.eval(BSHPrimaryExpression.java:102)
at bsh.BSHPrimaryExpression.eval(BSHPrimaryExpression.java:47)
at bsh.BSHBlock.evalBlock(BSHBlock.java:130)
at bsh.BSHBlock.eval(BSHBlock.java:80)
at bsh.BSHBlock.eval(BSHBlock.java:46)
at bsh.BSHTryStatement.eval(BSHTryStatement.java:86)
at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Interpreter.java:645)
at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Interpreter.java:739)
at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Interpreter.java:728)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter.bshInvoke(BeanShellInterpreter.java:169)
at org.apache.jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter.eval(BeanShellInterpreter.java:196)
at org.apache.jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement.processFileOrScript(BeanShellTestElement.java:151)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.BeanShellSampler.sample(BeanShellSampler.java:124)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:429)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Maybe you need to close file handles properly in your thread groups before attempting to delete?

Comment: Are all your threads finished when the script is launched ? It seems your file is still used by some thread or something else at this moment. If you try to write and delete another file (for debug), is it throwing the same exception ?

Answer (score 0):

One time I tried to send email which has attached results. I used tearDown Thread Group and my results were empty. In my opinion it is still open, when you try to delete.

Answer (score -1):

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
log.info("Deleting old csv data");
List files = FileUtils.listFiles(
                new File("${folderPath}"), new String[]    {"csv"}, true); 
for (File file : files) {
    file.delete();
}
log.info("csv data deleted");
```